# Angular material select auto width to selected option

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I can't seem to find a way for the  field to automatically expand based on what option is selected.

Either the field is too long or too short, and the text begins to truncate.

https://angular-5h6jd2.stackblitz.io

It doesn't seem there is a good way to do this with just css.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, albeit a bit hacky and a few side effects as far as overflow. Using in conjunction with clamp works well enough.

```
.mat-select-value {
    max-width: max-content !important;
}
```